# Page display using Spring mvc controller appends endpoint to page resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC controller that returns a page like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/subscriber")
public class SubscriberWebController {
    @GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String getSubscriber(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("id", id);
        return "subscriber/manage";
    }

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String addSubscriber() {
        return "subscriber/manage";
    }
}
```

The problem is that when manage.html loads, assets are loaded using http://localhost:8081/subscriber/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css rather than http://localhost:8081/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css. This results in a 404 while loading all page resources. I cannot seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

I have this configuration in my ApplicationConfiguration so as to help serve all static CSS and JS files.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
            .setCachePeriod(0);
}
```

Yet, the issue still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not say how you reference your CSS inside your manage.html

In case you want your CSS to load from  /vendor/nucleo/css/, then put your CSS reference like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css">
```

and put a mapping to your vendor package:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/vendor/**" location="/ACTUAL LOCATION/"/>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes that's how I reference my css in manage.html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css">

Comment: thanks for your answer @eugen, I took a cue from it and resolved mine, see details in my answer below

Comment: @mikaelovi great then!

Answer (score 1):

Taking a cue from @eugen's answer above, I modified my web configuration class thus:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
            .setCachePeriod(0);
}
```

and in my HTML pages, I reference static resources thus:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css">
```

Notice the "/" before vendor in the href attribute above. This resolves my issue